# Function specific optimization in GCC 4.4.3

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

In reference to my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6720779/1068), I found out a possilbe bug in GCC 4.4.3 when it did not support following pragmas in the source code for optimization (although it says 4.4.x onwards it does!)

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")

__attribute__((optimize("O3")))
```

Tried both above options but both gave compile time errors in the compiler itself(See the error message snapshot posted in the link mentioned above)

Now are there any further options for me to enable different optimization levels for different functions in my C code?

Comment: Just a note on the possible bug, it's likely merely a documentation error. Did you report it to the GCC folks? I'm sure they'd love to fix it

Comment: Does the same code compile when passed gcc -O3 on the command line?

Comment: I daresay some level of optimization makes no sense for just a "small" portion of code; I don't know if this is the case, though.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel - It compiles,executes fine when built with -O3.

Comment: AFAICT, and as stated in [Jonathan Leffler's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720779/c-code-optimization-using-pragma-gcc-optimize/6720907#6720907) to your previous question, this isn't a problem of compiler support, but rather a compiler bug causing a crash. you should try a newer version of gcc, and report the problem if it still exists.

Comment: `#pragma optimize` showed up in GCC 4.7. Are you using it (or above)?

Answer (score 3):

From the [online docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> Numbers are assumed to be an optimization level. Strings that begin with O are assumed to be an optimization option, while other options are assumed to be used with a -f prefix.

So, if you want the equivalent of the command line `-O3` you should probably use the just the number `3`  instead of `"O3"`.

I agree that this is a bug and should not generate an ICE, consider [reporting it](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) along with a small test case to the GCC guys.

Comment: I tried as you said, now it gave a warning: #pragma GCC optimize is not a string or number

Comment: I need to try it out, as soon as I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

> Now are there any further options for me to enable different optimization levels for different functions 
>   in my C code?

Your remaining option is to place the functions in their own .c file and compile that .c file with the optimization flag you want.