# What does '#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")' mean?

Tags: linux, gcc, pragma

I came through this line in project source code written before a function. I want to know, what is the use of it ?

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")

void somefunction()
{
  ....
}
```

Requesting to explain every argument used in the directive.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Please read gcc doc pragma section!

Comment: `#pragma` is *always* implementation-defined. Refer to your [compiler documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas).

Comment: @DevSolar: headline & flags says gcc :-)

Comment: Requesting people to try simply searching for things instead of demanding a personally tailored explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C code optimization using #pragma GCC optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720779/c-code-optimization-using-pragma-gcc-optimize)

Answer (score 18):

Pragmas are implementation specific but, in this case (gcc), it sets the optimisation level to 3 (high), similar in effect to using `-O3` on the command line.

Details on optimisation levels for `gcc`, and the individual flags that get set in response, can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: This seems to be a bit subtle - it is *similar* to using `-O3` on the command line, but not *equivalent*.  In particular, it doesn't seem to enable interprocedural optimizations like inlining.  [Example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9dYTG9The) - actually using `-O3` causes `please_inline_me()` to be inlined, but `#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")` doesn't.